# Problem finding the image path in Django in one of the apps

Tags: python, django, django-models, path, django-urls

I have 2 apps in my django project:
-accounts & -ticketsales
my project show images for ticketsales's model but dosen't show images for accounts's model,

when I run my project, ProfileImages folder create out of media folder(that contain project's image)
project's setting.py is:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static/")
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"media/")
```

my image field in accounts model.py is(dosen't show this image):

```
  ProfileImage=models.ImageField(upload_to="profileImagess",null=True)
```

profile view:

```
@login_required
def profileView(request):
    profile=request.user.profile
    context={
      "profile":profile
    }
    return render(request,"accounts/profile.html",context)
```

The image field in ticketsales model.py(show this image):

```
 Poster=models.ImageField(upload_to="concertImage",null=True
```

I want to show my images in project but this dosen't happen

Comment: It should show up. Maybe show us your account html template.

Comment: may be you don't add .url in end of profile image.
Example: <img src="{{ image_obj.image.url }}" alt="Image"> in the template